# Run an external shell command to mutate text

Tags: shell, mutability

I would like to run par or fmt to format my `.md` file.
In vim this would be `%!fmt` (for the whole buffer) or `13,16!fmt` (for line 13 - line 16).
What's the "emacs way" to achieve something like this

**PS:** I am aware of `evil-mode`(If I wanted vi keystrokes, I would have used vim) and the `M-!` key binding. I also am quite new to emacs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a region (for example via <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> or <kbd>M-h</kbd>, see "Mark" in Emacs' manual: <kbd>C-h r m Mark RET</kbd>)
2. Use `shell-command-on-region` with a prefix argument: <kbd>C-u M-|</kbd>

You can find more information in the Emacs documentation via <kbd>C-h F shell-command-on-region RET</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. That helped.